# How to createDataFrame in pyspark?

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, jupyter-notebook, py4j

Dear Spark users / creators,

I am trying to create a Spark DataFrame according to the documentation: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession.Builder

When I execute the following according to the documentation:

```
l = [('Alice', 1)]
spark.createDataFrame(l).collect()
```

the following error returns:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     62         try:
---> 63             return f(*a, **kw)
     64         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:

~/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o200.collectToPython.
: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 57
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:166)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:148)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:136)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:237)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.getClassReader(ClosureCleaner.scala:49)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:517)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3$$anonfun$visitMethodInsn$2.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:733)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1$$anonfun$foreach$2.apply(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashTable$class.foreachEntry(HashTable.scala:236)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap.foreachEntry(HashMap.scala:40)
    at scala.collection.mutable.HashMap$$anon$1.foreach(HashMap.scala:134)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$WithFilter.foreach(TraversableLike.scala:732)
    at org.apache.spark.util.FieldAccessFinder$$anon$3.visitMethodInsn(ClosureCleaner.scala:500)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readCode(ClassReader.java:2175)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.readMethod(ClassReader.java:1238)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:631)
    at org.apache.xbean.asm6.ClassReader.accept(ClassReader.java:355)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:307)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean$14.apply(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:392)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.org$apache$spark$util$ClosureCleaner$$clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:306)
    at org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.clean(ClosureCleaner.scala:162)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.clean(SparkContext.scala:2326)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2100)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2126)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1.apply(RDD.scala:990)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:112)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.withScope(RDD.scala:385)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.collect(RDD.scala:989)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeCollect(SparkPlan.scala:299)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3263)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$collectToPython$1.apply(Dataset.scala:3260)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectToPython(Dataset.scala:3260)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)


During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

IllegalArgumentException                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-9-1e7342225430> in <module>
----> 1 spark.createDataFrame(l).collect()

~/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py in collect(self)
    532         """
    533         with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
--> 534             sock_info = self._jdf.collectToPython()
    535         return list(_load_from_socket(sock_info, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))
    536 

~/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1255         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1256         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1257             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1258 
   1259         for temp_arg in temp_args:

~/anaconda2/envs/ipykernel_py3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     77                 raise QueryExecutionException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     78             if s.startswith('java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: '):
---> 79                 raise IllegalArgumentException(s.split(': ', 1)[1], stackTrace)
     80             raise
     81     return deco

IllegalArgumentException: 'Unsupported class file major version 57'
```

Is there anything I can look at to deal with this error? Any input is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

> Spark runs on Java 8/11, Scala 2.12, Python 2.7+/3.4+ and R 3.1+. Java 8 prior to version 8u92 support is deprecated as of Spark 3.0.

You will have to downgrade your Java 13 to any compatible version with PySpark

Comment: Thanks, @QuickSilver! I just install ```brew cask install adoptopenjdk8``` from the command line and specifiy the JAVA_HOME_PATH as  ```os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home"```, unfortunately the same error message returns, even though my jupyter kernel is restarted. Is there anything I missed?